# Reading a text file with JSON data in Java

Tags: java, json, file

I am trying to read a text file with JSON data in it using Java.

I use the following lines of code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
JSONObject ret; 
try {
    s = IOUtils.toString(is);
    ret = (JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(s);
}
```

I however, am not able to get the JSON value in the ret variable and I in fact get a null value in the String 's'. Is there something that I am overlooking here?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I am getting an exception at the " s = IOUtils.toString(ins);" line for some reason. I am not sure why? Is it not possible to use it this way, if the data in the file is JSON?
Can some one please throw some light on this?

Answer (score 4):

You may try out this example,

It worked well for me and can be extended easily to suit your json file
http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

> and I in fact get a null value in the
>   String 's'

Sounds like your file doesn't exist or is not readable. You can check this via `File.exists()` and `File.canRead()`

Comment: Brian, I did ensure that the file exists and it can be read. It satisfies both and I still get a null for the string.